# What is the most noob-friendly && up to date tutorial for testing smart contracts

Tags: nodeos

So I'm not sure how common of an issue this is but for the past week I have been struggling to spin up nodeos and haven't even been able to test any contract. I've watched or read multiple tutorials while setting up my ubuntu virtual machine and I think they were outdated as one of them had me install some plugins which now are returning me some sort of error because eosio removed support for it or something along those lines. It seems like every tutorial I look at is giving me completely different instructions.

Anyway bottom line is, for a complete beginner, what guide would you guys recommend for me to make this first time eos testing environment set up as seamless as possible. It has been a very frustrating process and I'd love to get this over with lol.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, it was very useful for me.

https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs

Answer (score 0):

The official giude says that you should [install eos from docker](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/getting-the-software). Another way to install it (the way i use), is to clone the [repository from github](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos) with the flag `--recursive` and then build it using `eosio_build.sh` and install it using `eosio_install.sh`. This second method may be quite long. If you are a beginner, i suggest you to use docker.